# Cannot build tex file on vs-code + texlive since upgrading to texlive 2022

Tags: pdftex, texlive, compilation-error, latex-workshop

I had worked both on windows & mac for the last 2 years. All my tex files are located on a drive, and with no problem at all.

But I decided last week to clean my windows computer (fresh windows install). I installed the latest version of tex live 2022 and switch from atom to vs code.

But since then, I canno't build some project on windows. Since I had some similar issues the first time, I have been looking for the past few days for write-enable, shell-escape, missing packages & co but I canno't understand where the error came from...

Here is a minimal example of a file that compile well on mac but not on windows :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[square,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, urlcolor=blue, urlbordercolor={0 0 1}, citecolor=black, citebordercolor={1 1 1}}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}


\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\textbf{RESUME -- bla bla.}\\

\textbf{\textit{Mots-clés -- bla bla.}}

\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont


\section{Introduction}
    some text

\section{work done}
    \subsection{TD}

\end{document}
```

with hundred errors (always the same) :

```
Argument of � has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.29 \section{Introduction}
                           
Runaway argument?
```

If you have any idea, it would save my day :)

Thanks a lots

PS : Here is the run that failed :

```
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error -recorder -output-directory="build"  "e:/val/OneDrive/m1/test.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
```

EDIT 1 : I've tried with unix and windows line endings and format, same error..

Comment: make sure your file is utf-8 encoded, and delete `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` which may be the source of the error

Comment: do you really want `\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont` not `\normalsize` (which is `\fontsize{10pt}{12pt}\selectfont`  ??? 10 on 10 is _very_ tight spacing: descenders like y or g will almost touch any capital letters of the line below.

Comment: It's a template given by a professor for a lab report ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler example is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont
\textbf{RESUME -- bla bla.}% No!!! badness 10000\\

\textbf{\textit{Mots-clés -- bla bla.}}

\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont

\section{Introduction}
    some text

\section{work done}
    \subsection{TD}

\end{document}
```

simply remove

`\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`

which is increasingly incompatible with the UTF handling in LaTeX. UTF-8 has been the default encoding for some years, so specifying `[utf8]` would be harmless although unnecessary. However the non standard `[utf8x]` option should be avoided, as seen here. (I have tried to reach the maintainer without success so far)

Comment: Indeed it fix the issue. It's a shame cause i've used utf8x (french accent back in the day) for a long time without knowing.
I do not understand why it work on mac and not on windows, but as long as it works, it's fine for me.

Thanks a lots, it was very helpfull

Comment: @Valoche I want to make `utf8x` be an alias for `utf8` (which does nothing as it is the default) but it would be best if I could reach the package maintainer but no success so far. That would keep documents like yours working with no error, but copyright and ctan rules make updating packages when you can not reach the maintainer difficult

Comment: @Valoche mac/windows is not the issue: it will fail on the mac as well if you update there.

Comment: why it is a shame? You don't need it (and if you have only french accents you never needed it), the kernel support for utf8 is quite enough.